# No puedo usar ngModel en pantalla de Login

Tags: angular

Tengo un componente login y en su html tengo:

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-title>Inicio de sesion</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-content>
        <p>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input [(ngmodel)]="user" type="text"  name="user" matInput placeholder="Usuario">
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>
    
        <p>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input  [(ngmodel)]="password"  type="password" name="password" matInput placeholder="Contraseña">
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>
        <div>
            <button (click)="login()" mat-raised-button>Iniciar Sesion</button>
        </div>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

> ```
> error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngmodel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
>     <input [(ngmodel)]="user" type="text"  name="user" matInput placeholder="Usuario">  
>                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**
> ```

He visto otras preguntas y no pude solucionarlo, ya importe fomrsmodule:

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' }),
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema lo tienes en que [(ngmodel)] tiene que ser [([ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel))]. Entiendo que tienes declarado las variables en componente con extension *.ts.
De todos modos te adjunto un ejemplo de como he hecho un login.

**Componente**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../services/authentication.service';
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  error:boolean;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private router: Router,
              private authService: AuthenticationService,
              private matSnackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      username: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      password: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    })
  }

  login(){
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value.username, this.loginForm.value.password)
      .subscribe(user =>{
        this.authService.storeCurrentUser(user);
        console.log(user.id + "successfully logged in");
        this.error=false;
        this.router.navigate(['']).then(()=>{
          window.location.reload();
        });
      },()=> this.matSnackBar.open('Username or password incorrect.','Close',{
        duration:2000,
      }))
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<section id="login">
  <div style="text-align: center;margin-top: 10%;">
    <h2 class="title">Login as user</h2>

    <form (ngSubmit)="login()" [formGroup]="loginForm" novalidate>

      <div>
        <mat-form-field style="width: 20%" appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Enter your username</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Username" formControlName="username" required>
          <mat-error *ngIf="!loginForm.value.username.valid">Need username</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div>
        <mat-form-field style="width: 20%" appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Enter your password</mat-label>
          <input matInput formControlName="password" type="password" required>
          <mat-error *ngIf="!loginForm.value.password.valid">Need password</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>



        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit"
                [disabled]="loginForm.invalid">Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo..Funciono a la perfeccion